# Why show me error when i convert JSON to string in C#

Tags: c#, android, json

**My code is  here for converting JSON to string in C#**

here is my class

```
public class Datum
{
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class TableDetails
{     
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

}

here i parse this

```
TableDetails table = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TableDetails>(context.DataFrame.ToString());
```

**Error is here**

> {"Error converting value \"[{\"quantity\":\"1\",\"price\":\"350\",\"name\":\"Thai Fried Chicken\"}]\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AlchameyWebsoket.Datum]'. Path 'Data', line 1, position 82."}

I send this string from an android app here is the code i use in android

try{

```
                    JSONObject mainObj=new JSONObject();

                    JSONArray arr=new JSONArray();
                    for(int i=0;i<Memory.finalOrder.size();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
                        jo.put("name",Memory.finalOrder.get(i).getName());
                        jo.put("quantity",Memory.finalOrder.get(i).getQuantity());
                        jo.put("price",Memory.finalOrder.get(i).getPrice());

                        arr.put(jo);
                    }

                    mainObj.put("TableName",Memory.tableName);
                    mainObj.put("Data",arr.toString());
```

Please help me out of this problem

Comment: can you share your Json string. It seems that your JSON string have some issue

Comment: @EdPlunkett How do you know he serialize  List<Datum>.

Comment: {"Data":"[{\"quantity\":\"1\",\"price\":\"325\",\"name\":\"Nachos(Beef)\"},{\"quantity\":\"1\",\"price\":\"395\",\"name\":\"Hot Buffalo Wings\"}]","TableName":"Table 1"}

Comment: I send this string from an android app   here is the code           http://codepaste.net/h1eowa

Comment: @ShobhitWalia I made a mistaken assumption based on the JSON quoted in the error string he pasted.

Comment: when i receive  the json string it contains some   back slash (\)  in Data array automatically

Comment: @amitghosh Is that the actual JSON? Does `context.DataFrame.ToString()` return that actual exact string with all the escaped quotes? What you pasted in the comment looks like `Data` is a string which contains an escaped JSON string, rather than a actual JSON array definition.

Comment: here is the exception  https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kt47gu9fqw7ssb/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: escaped quotes are automatically added when i receive this string . I use alchemy websockets for receiving data

Comment: Thanks guys ... I solve the problem just replace a line of java code before mainObj.put("Data",arr.toString()); after mainObj.put("Data",arr);  for toString(); method its added some escaped operator