# preview JSON on DataGridView

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I have an ASP MVC Web Api that returns these data as Json :

```
"[{\"OpID\":15,\"DeviceID\":1,\"DeviceType\":\"LED1\",\"DeviceState\":true,\"TurnOnTime\":\"2016-07-26T21:10:05.607\",\"TurnOffTime\":null,\"ToggleTime\":\"2016-07-26T21:10:05.61\",\"ToggleHour\":null},{\"OpID\":16,\"DeviceID\":5,\"DeviceType\":\"TV\",\"DeviceState\":true,\"TurnOnTime\":\"2016-07-26T21:10:09.283\",\"TurnOffTime\":null,\"ToggleTime\":\"2016-07-26T21:10:09.283\",\"ToggleHour\":null}]"
```

I`m trying to deserialize it using this code :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://engeek.azurewebsites.net/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/operation").Result;               
                string str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                            
                List<operation> myDeserializedObjList = (List<operation>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str , typeof(List<operation>));
                dataGridView1.DataSource = myDeserializedObjList;
```

and here is my model:

```
class operation
    {
        [JsonProperty("OpID")]
        public int OpID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("DeviceID")]
        public Nullable<int> DeviceID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("DeviceType")]
        public string DeviceType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("DeviceState")]
        public Nullable<bool> DeviceState { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("TurnOnTime")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TurnOnTime { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("TurnOffTime")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TurnOffTime { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ToggleTime")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ToggleTime { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ToggleHour")]
        public Nullable<int> ToggleHour { get; set; }
    }
```

and the serialization code :

```
public string Getoperation()
        {
            var data = new List<operation>();
            data = db.operations.ToList();
            string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None);
            return str;
        }
```

It gives me :
couldn`t convert or cast from string to List

What should I do ?

Comment: How does that string `str` get from that method to the client? Is there some other code that sends it to the client? If there is, can you please add that code to your question?

Comment: Are you doing [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/227638/424129)?

Comment: I haven't found anything wrong with your code, but I would call the deserializer like this (avoid double casting): 
List<operation> myDeserializedObjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<operation>>(str);

Comment: It gives me the same error !

Comment: @MohamadMaher Please show the code where you return the JSON string to the client.

Comment: I tested the deserialization part here and it worked perfectly

Comment: which exactly line are you getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the MVC code where you are creating the JSON response, you are serializing the `List<operation>` as a JSON string, and then serializing that JSON string again.

Show the code where you serialize the `List<operation>` (that part looks good, thanks!) and the code where you return that JSON string to the client, and I'll probably be able to show you where that's happening.

You have a slight variation on [the same problem this other guy had yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38643784/424129), except he only double-encoded one branch of his object, while you double-encoded the entire thing.

Comment: public string Getoperation()
        {
            var data = new List<operation>();
            data = db.operations.ToList();
            string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None);
            return str;


        }

Comment: @MohamadMaher, per your posted code and comment there shouldn't be any issue in deserializing. Somewhere you have done some mistake